# Why we don't care about bit order?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking

Recently I've learned some Windows socket programming to achieve some socket connection stuff.

Inside the code we use some functions like htonl(), htons() to convert our data from host byte order to network byte order, or so called big-endian, since in some machines data is stored as little-endian, like Intel's CPU as I know.

But what I confused is that doesn't the really important thing is the bit order instead of byte?

Since bit is the minimum unit that computers used, not byte.
Let's say we want to pass an u_short u=18 to another machine by a machine use little-endian.

In our machine, u's first byte, the least significant one is 2 and second byte, the most significant one is 1, let me express this by [2][1].

So we need to call htons(u) first to convert [2][1] into [1][2] and send it to network.

The remote machine will receive 2 first, but 2 is expressed by a sequence of bits which the machine actually receive are 0000-0010, how does the machine know this byte is 2? Won't it think 0000-0010 represents 64?(0100-0000) Do all machines store bytes in the same way?

Comment: Endianess is by definition a byte-order term, not a bit-order term. There is no "bit order" in memory, since memory addresses are in **byte units**. The only possible difference in bit-level interpretation, is by your compiler, when you're using bit-field structures. And data sent over the network does not contain this type of information.

Comment: Well that translation, if necessary, could happen at the network protocol level, not the application level. However, the network protocol doesn't know how many bytes in a packet are grouped together: (is that 2 `short`s, or 1 `int`?)

Comment: Why would the program on the receiving machine think that, if it's receiving the data from the network?

Comment: The IETF has some documents regarding bit order. For example, "_3.2. Network Bit Order

     For certain low-level protocols or compression-oriented media
     types, bit-order may be an issue.  When possible, big-endian is
     encouraged for consistancy with Network Byte Order._"

Answer (score 2):

"Bit Ordering" is specified by the protocols used to transfer data from the hardware (like your network card/port) to host memory.

Technically, this applies in many, many cases. Like, you might wonder the same question if a Harddrive on a machine that stores bits in one order `01234567` is transferred to a machine that stores bits in the opposite order `76543210`, whether it'll read the data correctly or not.

But the simple answer is that it always reads correctly, because the protocols used to map the hard drives to the system bus specify the exact ordering of the bits as they are "presented" to host memory.

Network cards and networking hardware have a similar behavior: They have a standardized "bit ordering" they use in hardware, and as part of the hardware protocol, it "presents" those bits to the Host in whatever form the host expects them.

"Byte Ordering", of course, is a separate thing, and more difficult to deal with, because network hardware and storage hardware only recognize "streams of bytes" (Yes, I'm oversimplifying), and don't much care for what those bytes actually mean.

But in terms of "Bit Ordering", unless you're writing code "On the Metal", so to speak, you don't need to think about it.

Comment: when you say "protocols", you mean those work in the physical layer?

Comment: @HECHANG Yes. The hardware has specifications on how they should handle individual bits, and also specifications on how those bits should be presented to the CPU (and how the CPU should interpret them). So unless you're writing Metal code (i.e., you're writing those literal bit/bus interactions), those are details you don't need to know about.